# Updating List View Web Part property in page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, development, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a List View web part (In the page > Add web part > App > document library name). I need to update the **TitleUrl** property of this web part through C# code.

The SaveChanges() method below works for my visual web parts, but not for the List view webpart. I get an error saying: *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation*

```
webpartManager = myPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
webPart.TitleUrl = titleURL;
webpartManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
```

I did a casting as below

```
XsltListViewWebPart listViewWebPart = (XsltListViewWebPart)webPart;
listViewWebPart.TitleUrl = titleURL;
webpartManager.SaveChanges(listViewWebPart);
```

But I get the error at SaveChanges() method.

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll but was not handled in user code

The error description is as below

```
>    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[]
> index)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.DoesPersonalizedPropertValueMatchDefaultValue(SPPersonalizablePropertyEntry
> spPersonalizablePropertyEntry, Object value, Control defaultControl)  
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(PersonalizationScope
> scope, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags,
> BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode
> mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags,
> SPSerializationBinderBase serializationBinder,
> BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode
> mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags,
> SPSerializationBinderBase serializationBinder)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.SaveChangesCore(SPLayoutProperties
> layoutProperties, Boolean httpGet, Boolean saveCompressed, Boolean
> skipRightsCheck, Boolean skipSafeAgainstScriptCheck, WebPartTypeInfo&
> newTypeId, Byte[]& newAllUsersProperties, Byte[]&
> newPerUserProperties, String[]& newLinks)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.SaveChangesInternal(SPLayoutProperties
> layoutProperties, Boolean skipRightsCheck, Boolean
> skipSafeAgainstScriptCheck)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.SaveChanges(Guid
> storageKey)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.SaveChanges(WebPart
> webPart)    at
> WSP.ABC.ABC.ABCWindow.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ChangeWebPartProperties>b__4()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
> secureCode)
```

any reason why ?

Comment: Try this `ListViewWebPart wp = (ListViewWebPart)webpart;`

Comment: @AmalHashim Actually I tried that before. It gives a invalid cast exception which is the reason why i cast it now to a XsltListViewWebPart

Comment: Even i too facing the same issue, can any one has solution to this, or any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works for me. 
Instead of casting, I use the Properties collection.

You would of course have to change the creation of the context / authentication and the way you look for the specific WebPart which in this case is done by title.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts;

namespace SharePointTest1 {


  class Program {

    private static void ShowWebPartProperties(string webFullUrl, string fileName, string webPartTitle) {
      using (var context = new ClientContext(webFullUrl)) {
        context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileName);

        LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        context.Load(wpm.WebParts,
        wps => wps.Include(
        wp => wp.WebPart.Title));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (WebPartDefinition wpd in wpm.WebParts) {
          WebPart wp = wpd.WebPart;
          if (wp.Title == webPartTitle) {
            Console.WriteLine(wp.Title + " found. Showing properties:");
            var properties = wp.Properties;
            context.Load(properties);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var item in properties.FieldValues.Keys.OrderBy(m => m).ToList()) {
              Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", item, properties.FieldValues[item]));
            }
            break;
          }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
      }
    }




    private static void ChangeWebPartProperty(string webFullUrl, string fileName, string webPartTitle, string propertyName, object propertyValue) {
      using (var context = new ClientContext(webFullUrl)) {
        context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileName);

        LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        context.Load(wpm.WebParts,
        wps => wps.Include(
        wp => wp.WebPart.Title));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (WebPartDefinition wpd in wpm.WebParts) {
          WebPart wp = wpd.WebPart;
          if (wp.Title == webPartTitle) {
            Console.WriteLine(wp.Title + " found");
            wp.Properties[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            wpd.SaveWebPartChanges();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      try {
        ShowWebPartProperties("http://localhost/DocumentLibraryTest/",
          "/DocumentLibraryTest/SitePages/Home.aspx",
          "Documents");

        ChangeWebPartProperty("http://localhost/DocumentLibraryTest/",
        "/DocumentLibraryTest/SitePages/Home.aspx",
        "Documents", "TitleUrl", "http://evolootion.net");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Finished");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```